# Flutter web not printing entire page

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, flutter-web

I am facing a problem on printing a web page which was built in flutter.
[image]

The above image is my actual web page. When I print it using (ctrl P) browser shortcut. I
get only half of the page.
[image: web page when I use (ctrl+p) to print]
In other websites, When I use the browser shortcut to print, it scale to the paper size and prints the entire content.
How to print entire page using browser print shortcut(ctrl p) in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

In the print dialog you might want to change the Layout to Landscape.

If it still doesn't fit all check More settings and reduce the Scale

Comment: That's ok. But, I want to print in portrait itself, such a way that when I press (ctrl p) It should scale automatically and print the entire content in portrait (like how other websites are doing).